# python struct unpack into a dict

Tags: python, unpack

struct.unpack will unpack data into a tuple.  Is there an equivalent that will store data into a dict instead?

In my particular problem, I am dealing with a fixed-width binary format.  I want to be able, in one fell swoop, to unpack and store the values in a dict (currently I manually walk through the list and assign dict values)

Comment: I don't think so. But the `dict` constructor can take a list or iterator of (name, value) pairs to initialize with. That might help you.

Comment: You might also be interested in `namedtuple` if you don't need to modify the object after creating it.

Comment: What do you expect the keys to be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `struct` documentation shows [an example](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html?highlight=namedtuple#examples) of unpacking directly into a `namedtuple`. You can combine this with `namedtuple._asdict()` to get your one swell foop:

```
>>> import struct
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> record = 'raymond   \x32\x12\x08\x01\x08'
>>> Student = namedtuple('Student', 'name serialnum school gradelevel')
>>> Student._asdict(Student._make(struct.unpack('<10sHHb', record)))
{'school': 264, 'gradelevel': 8, 'name': 'raymond   ', 'serialnum': 4658}
>>>
```

If it matters, note that in Python 2.7 `_asdict()` returns an `OrderedDict`...

Comment: Heh probably should have checked the web doc.  No indication of this in the python `help(struct)`

Comment: interesting answer.  i see it's a dynamically generated function, but why is _asdict() with a prepended underscore?

Comment: Using private methods - great idea.

Comment: @FogleBird - not sure what you mean by private methods. `namedtuple._asdict()` is documented here: http://www.python.org/doc//current/library/collections.html#collections.somenamedtuple._asdict. And I took the usage of `namedtuple._make()` directly from the documentation linked in the answer. What's the recommended best practice here?

Comment: The spaces after raymond makes me crazy to debug the code.

Comment: Why the code can not run under python3: `TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface`?

Comment: You can rewrite the fifth line more concisely as `Student(*struct.unpack('<10sHHb', record))._asdict()`

Comment: this solution is significantly slower than `dict(zip(keys,struct.unpack(...)))`

Answer (score 12):

If you're on 2.6 or newer you can use namedtuple + struct.pack/unpack like this:

```
import collections
import struct

Point = collections.namedtuple("Point", "x y z")

data = Point(x=1, y=2, z=3)

packed_data = struct.pack("hhh", *data)
data = Point(*struct.unpack("hhh", packed_data))

print data.x, data.y, data.z
```

Answer (score 9):

Do you want something like this?

```
keys = ['x', 'y', 'z']
values = struct.unpack('<III', data)
d = dict(zip(keys, values))
```

Comment: that's what im doing now.  I was hoping for something a bit slicker

Comment: its a list that is being walked through (unless zip does something clever that doesnt involve walking through the list).

Comment: I feel this solution is fine, and already slicker than mucking around with `collections.namedtuple`

Comment: just as an aside this method is **MUCH** faster than the named tuple version